# Spring Rest Template with OAUTH

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

My controller layer is wrapped with spring oauth2. I am writing an integration test to test the api calls to controller, so I decided to use `RestTemplate`.

Following are commands I use via curl:

```
curl -v --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt  "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?client_id=my-trusted-client&grant_type=password&scope=trust&username=xxxx&password=xxxxxx"
```

This returns an access token which I use to make the call to the api :

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer Access toekn value" "http://localhost:8080/profile/1.json"
```

While using `RestTemplate`, I was able to get the access token, but now I want to pass this token to make api calls:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization: Bearer", accessToken);
    System.out.println(accessToken);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    System.out.println(restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/xxxx",HttpMethod.GET,entity,Object.class));
```

However, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
at com.gogii.service.SKUService.testGetAllSKU(SKUService.java:20)
```

How can we make authenticated calls using `RestTemplate`?

Comment: So, are you passing "accessToken" with each REQUEST to the server. So, I assume your REST API is stateless and you keep its state stateless by sending accessToken everytime. Is this a secure solution? Are you using it in a production environment?

Answer (score 12):

I was setting wrong parameter in header.. it should be

```
headers.set("Authorization","Bearer "+accessToken);
```

Comment: How do you obtain the access token from the request? Where is your acessTOken field set?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me , for oauth2 API.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("Authorization","Bearer "+"ACCESS-TOKEN");
```

space characters important while setting Authorization .