# How to pass on the original Oauth2 bearer token between Spring microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, resttemplate

We have a few Spring micro services which communicate with each other via rest (Spring's RestTemplate). There is Oauth2 authorization applied in all of them and the JWT token is extended with a few custom fields (i.e. userRole, userId etc).

My problem is the following:

When we call a service which also calls another micro service via RestTemplate, the original bearer token (Oauth2) is not forwarded when the micro services are communicating with each other. We can't get a response from other services, because we are unauthorized. I can't find a neat solution.

Note, that we do not want to acquire a new token for the second call, because that would affect our performance. That is what OAuth2RestTemplate is doing, but we just want to pass the original bearer token.

As I researched on Stackoverflow, one solution would be to  [manually add the bearer + token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971119/spring-rest-template-with-oauth) as an Authorization header, and use .exchange() , but I think there should be a configuration in spring, which will make RestTemplate pass on the original Authorization header, or something similar.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while testing in local. The below configuration in my application.yml file fixed it. The token gets passed from one service call to another.

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: SEMAPHORE
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000